# Puzzling behavior of `Assumptions` in `Solve`

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, assumptions

With `Wolfram Language 13.3.0 Engine` when solving the following equation:

```
 fs = k s (-4 + (4 + Sqrt[2]) s)
 Solve[fs==0, s] 
 Solve[fs==0, s, Assumptions->{k>0}]
```

we find in both cases (with or without the assumption) two values, `0` and `4/(4 + Sqrt[2])` which is correct. If, however, I ask:

```
 Solve[fs==0, s, Assumptions->{k==1}]
```

then I get `0` and `2 (4 - Sqrt[2]) / 7`. It took me a while to see that this is
in fact the same solution! (the actual expression was slightly more complex, so
I first thought there really was a difference in the things that I had asked, but I couldn't find it... This
is just the simplified version to keep this post short!)

What could cause the solver to return the result in a different form?
And more importantly, is there a way to require a "standard form" for
expressions with square roots, which will avoid any ambiguity?!

Comment: I assume you are asking why in one case it returns $\frac{4}{4+\sqrt{2}}$ and in the other case it returned $-\frac{2}{7} \left(\sqrt{2}-4\right)$.  it is most likely due to different code path used. But the important thing is that `LeafCount` is same which is $11$. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgENT.png)  so it is a tie.  So for a computer there is no difference between the two results and since these are the same  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptCp0.png)  then the computer is happy and done its job.

Comment: You may want to try [`RootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootReduce.html).

Comment: @Domen `RootReduce` does solve it indeed!